# Dividing integers by floats resulting in proportional integers

Tags: algorithm, integer, division, integer-division

Recently I've came across a hard problem solving while doing a project. And I'd like to ask you guys for a solution / algorithm to solve it, because I'm really struggling to think about a clever idea to do so.

I have an arbitrary number of floats:

- *f1, f2, ..., fn* where *f1 + f2 + ... + fn = 1*

and one integer:

- *I* where *I > 0*.

I need to divide the integer *I* into the floats as if I was distributing indivisible things. So basically the proportion must hold in some sense, in the sense that the biggest float must get the biggest integer. A good metaphor is as if i'm dividing stocks that can't be split.

If the first investor has 0.6 percent of the stocks and the second has 0.4, given 1 stock to split, i'd give it to the first one (100% 0%). If had 2 stocks, I'd give one to the first and one to the second one (50% 50%). Notice that I always want the split to be as proportional (as close to 60% 40%) as possible.

The problem itself is not terribly defined, but there is some sense of what should happen and what shouldn't. Some examples that easily pop in my mind are:

1. If: *f1 = 0.4, f2 = 0.3, f3 = 0.3, I = 1* then I need *f1-result = 1, f2-result = 0, f3-result = 0*,
2. If: *f1 = 0.4, f2 = 0.4, f3 = 0.2, I = 1* then I need *f1-result = 1, f2-result = 0, f3-result = 0* **or** *f1-result = 0, f2-result = 1, f3-result = 0*
3. If: *f1 = 0.6, f2 = 0.25, f3 = 0.15, I = 5* then I need *f1-result = 3, f2-result = 2, f3-result = 1*.

Comment: Look at going from votes in a general election to seats to find ways from intelligible to screw-ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach it, at least initially.

Every bucket has a desired amount that it needs. This is based on their float values, and all the float values sum to 1.

So, go through the "objects" to be distributed one by one. To figure out which bucket gets it, you need to find the bucket that is *below* its desired amount by the largest differential (just choose the first if there are more than one equally under their desired level). This is the "unhappiest" bucket.

Then you distribute that object to that bucket, adjust the figures and move on to the next object. That means an object is always distributed in such a way to make the lives of the unhappiest buckets a little better (good grief, this sounds like I'm a social worker).

By way of example, let's start distributing objects to three buckets (that want 50%, 30%, and 20% respectively), based on that algorithm described above.

The second figure in the parentheses is the deviation of each bucket from its desired percentage so, at each stage, we choose the bucket which is the furthest below that desired level, the unhappiest (indicated by `*`):

```
BucketA (50%)  BucketB (30%)  BucketC (20%)
-------------  -------------  -------------
 0 (0%,-50*)    0 (0%,-30)     0 (0%,-20)
 1 (100%,+50)   0 (0%,-30*)    0 (0%,-20)
 1 (50%,+0)     1 (50%,+20)    0 (0%,-20*)
 1 (33%,-17*)   1 (33%,+3)     1 (33%,+13)
 2 (50%,+0)     1 (25%,-5*)    1 (25%,+5)
 2 (40%,-10*)   2 (40%,+10)    1 (20%,+0)
 3 (50%,+0)     2 (33%,+3)     1 (17%,-3*)
 3 (43%,-7*)    2 (29%,-1)     2 (29%,+9)
 4 (50%,+0)     2 (25%,-5*)    2 (25%,+5)
 4 (44%,-6*)    3 (33%,+3)     2 (22%,+2)
 5 (50%,+0)     3 (30%,+0)     2 (20%,+0)
```

Note that the initial condition has all buckets at `0%` even though that's not *technically* correct (it could just as easily be considered `100%` or even `3.14159%` based on the undefined divide-by-zero nature of the calculation). However, it's a good way to ensure the initial distribution is to the bucket that wants the highest percentage, after which the percentages become well defined.

You can see from that table above that the distribution of objects eventually leads towards the desired outcome.

---

And, if you want some code you can play with to see this in action (and let's face it, who *wouldn't* want that?), see the following Python program:

```
desiredPct = [50, 30, 20]
bucket = [0, 0, 0]
count = 0

# Allocate first item specially so no concern with div-by-zero.

idx = desiredPct.index(max(desiredPct))
happy_min = -desiredPct[idx]
bucket[idx] += 1
count += 1

actualPct = [x * 100 / count for x in bucket]
print "Unhappiest %6.2f @ %d, want %s%%, have %s (%s%%)" % (happy_min, idx, desiredPct, bucket, actualPct)

# Allocate all others in loop.

for i in range(99):
    # Get most disadvantaged bucket.

    idx = 0
    happy_min = bucket[idx] * 100 / sum(bucket) - desiredPct[idx]
    for j in range(1, len(bucket)):
        happy = bucket[j] * 100 / sum(bucket) - desiredPct[j]
        if happy < happy_min:
            idx = j
            happy_min = happy

    bucket[idx] += 1
    count += 1
    actualPct = [x * 100 / count for x in bucket]
    print "Unhappiest %6.2f @ %d, want %s%%, have %s (%s%%)" % (happy_min, idx, desiredPct, bucket, actualPct)
```

which outputs:

```
Unhappiest -50.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [1, 0, 0] ([100, 0, 0]%)
Unhappiest -30.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [1, 1, 0] ([50, 50, 0]%)
Unhappiest -20.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [1, 1, 1] ([33, 33, 33]%)
Unhappiest -17.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [2, 1, 1] ([50, 25, 25]%)
Unhappiest  -5.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [2, 2, 1] ([40, 40, 20]%)
Unhappiest -10.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [3, 2, 1] ([50, 33, 16]%)
Unhappiest  -4.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [3, 2, 2] ([42, 28, 28]%)
Unhappiest  -8.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [4, 2, 2] ([50, 25, 25]%)
Unhappiest  -5.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [4, 3, 2] ([44, 33, 22]%)
Unhappiest  -6.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [5, 3, 2] ([50, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest   0.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [6, 3, 2] ([54, 27, 18]%)
Unhappiest  -3.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [6, 4, 2] ([50, 33, 16]%)
Unhappiest  -4.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [6, 4, 3] ([46, 30, 23]%)
Unhappiest  -4.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [7, 4, 3] ([50, 28, 21]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [7, 5, 3] ([46, 33, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -4.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [8, 5, 3] ([50, 31, 18]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [8, 5, 4] ([47, 29, 23]%)
Unhappiest  -3.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [9, 5, 4] ([50, 27, 22]%)
Unhappiest  -3.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [9, 6, 4] ([47, 31, 21]%)
Unhappiest  -3.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [10, 6, 4] ([50, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest   0.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [11, 6, 4] ([52, 28, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [11, 7, 4] ([50, 31, 18]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [11, 7, 5] ([47, 30, 21]%)
Unhappiest  -3.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [12, 7, 5] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [12, 8, 5] ([48, 32, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [13, 8, 5] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [13, 8, 6] ([48, 29, 22]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [14, 8, 6] ([50, 28, 21]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [14, 9, 6] ([48, 31, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [15, 9, 6] ([50, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest   0.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [16, 9, 6] ([51, 29, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [16, 10, 6] ([50, 31, 18]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [16, 10, 7] ([48, 30, 21]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [17, 10, 7] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [17, 11, 7] ([48, 31, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [18, 11, 7] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [18, 11, 8] ([48, 29, 21]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [19, 11, 8] ([50, 28, 21]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [19, 12, 8] ([48, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [20, 12, 8] ([50, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest   0.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [21, 12, 8] ([51, 29, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [21, 13, 8] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [21, 13, 9] ([48, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [22, 13, 9] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [22, 14, 9] ([48, 31, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [23, 14, 9] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [23, 14, 10] ([48, 29, 21]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [24, 14, 10] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [24, 15, 10] ([48, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -2.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [25, 15, 10] ([50, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest   0.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [26, 15, 10] ([50, 29, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [26, 16, 10] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [26, 16, 11] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [27, 16, 11] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [27, 17, 11] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [28, 17, 11] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [28, 17, 12] ([49, 29, 21]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [29, 17, 12] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [29, 18, 12] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [30, 18, 12] ([50, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest   0.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [31, 18, 12] ([50, 29, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [31, 19, 12] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [31, 19, 13] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [32, 19, 13] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [32, 20, 13] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [33, 20, 13] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [33, 20, 14] ([49, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [34, 20, 14] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [34, 21, 14] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [35, 21, 14] ([50, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest   0.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [36, 21, 14] ([50, 29, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [36, 22, 14] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [36, 22, 15] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [37, 22, 15] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [37, 23, 15] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [38, 23, 15] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [38, 23, 16] ([49, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [39, 23, 16] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [39, 24, 16] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [40, 24, 16] ([50, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest   0.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [41, 24, 16] ([50, 29, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [41, 25, 16] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [41, 25, 17] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [42, 25, 17] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [42, 26, 17] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [43, 26, 17] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [43, 26, 18] ([49, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [44, 26, 18] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [44, 27, 18] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [45, 27, 18] ([50, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest   0.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [46, 27, 18] ([50, 29, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [46, 28, 18] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [46, 28, 19] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [47, 28, 19] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [47, 29, 19] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [48, 29, 19] ([50, 30, 19]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 2, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [48, 29, 20] ([49, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [49, 29, 20] ([50, 29, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 1, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [49, 30, 20] ([49, 30, 20]%)
Unhappiest  -1.00 @ 0, want [50, 30, 20]%, have [50, 30, 20] ([50, 30, 20]%)
```

This also shows that, once you *get* to the desired outcome for the first time, the distribution of objects tends to stay close to what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Investor `j` should get at least `floor(fj*I)` shares. To distribute the excess shares, first determine their number (`x = I - sum(floor(fj*I) for all j)`) and then select the `x`th largest element of the array of fractions `fj*I - floor(fj*I)`. Everybody with a fraction larger than this gets one more share; people with exactly this fraction get one or zero as needed to make the totals work.

The running time is `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of investors.

Comment: This will not work properly. Imagine you had 0.2 0.4 and 0.6, and you have to split 3 stocks, you would then have to distribute 2 stocks to the investor with 0.6 one stock to the 0.4 one and zero to the 0.3 one. The distance of your distribution (33.3% 33.3% 33.3%) to the original one  (20% 40% 60%)  is (13.3 + 6.7 + 16.7 = 36.7) whereas following the optimal one it would be (0%  33.3% + 66.6% ), where the distance is (20 + 6.7 + 6.6 = 33.3).

Comment: @ManoelRibeiro No, this algorithm would not split the shares evenly.

Answer (score 0):

You started the question with *f1+f2+....+fn=1* but you refer only three floats in the end.
The easy way to solve this is to multiply the smallest *fi* to a power of ten (10^p) as to get an integer value. You subtract the amount to be distributed from the whole number (10^p) to figure out how much you have to get back from each float to arrive to the distributed amount supposing that you brought an additional amount up to (10^p) as each one gets its share times (10^p). 
You do this by a repetitive scheme and first you collect back from each float the amount in excess of the distribution amount. On the next iterations you collect back one unit from each float sorted in ascending order but you should consider not to go negative. Test if you got your whole amount back after each deduction.

So to exemplify for 
f1=0.6, f2=0.25, f3=015 and I=5. 
Declare a matrix f of floats with f(i,j) where i=3 and j=2 it is a  matrix on two columns and three rows. store the floats in the first column and sort the matrix ascending. Access the first element o the matrix f(1,1) we get 0.15. 
Convert this to integer as It = f(1,1)* (10^(number of decimals(f(1,1))) and we get It=0.15*(10^2). That is It=15. Populate the matrix second column with the integers

```
f(1,2)=15
f(2,2)=25
f(3,2)=60
```

Now I have to get back the amount of 10^2-5=95. set It=95. First round everyone possessing over 5 gives the excess back. So I get the following (for easing the example I am skipping the test that f(i,2) > 5 )

```
10 = f(1,2)-5; f(1,2)=f(1,2)-10
20 = f(2,2)-5; f(2,2)=f(2,2)-20 
55 = f(3,2)-5; f(3,2)=f(3,2)-55
```

Till know I claimed back *10+20+55=85*. I have to go for another *ten*.Now each one has five. This is made in three iterations. First second and third run of the loop will get one unit from each is 9 units . *Now I got back 94*  I still have to get *one unit* back and this will be *claimed back from f(2,1)* and the loop will exit as i have reached my 95 units. After three iterations and one step of the fourth iteration my final matrix is

```
  f(1,2)=1, 
  f(2,2)=2, 
  f(2,3)=2.
```

Which for obvious reason sums up to 5 
The iteration algorithm is a simple one. It iterates the f(i,2). It tests if f(i,s)>0, then It deducts one unit from f(i,2); adds this one unit to amount claimed back so far and test if the amount equals the total amount to get back. if true it breaks the loop.